# Random identifiers: secure VS unique. What to chose?

Tags: perl, random

Some times when we want to identify something we generate IDentifier for this object.

Sometimes we use just [`rand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) sometimes we want something more reliable. Currently I am between:

1. [Data::UUID](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::UUID)
2. [Crypt::PRNG](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PRNG)

**Would be there any difference between results of these two methods?**

```
$id = Data::UUID->new->create_bin;    #
$id = Crypt::PRNG::random_bytes(16);  # https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PRNG#random_bytes
```

Both are 16bytes random. Regardless of interface are there further differences?

**UPD**
In my case I use ID as random string to identificate query to [Stripe](http://stripe.com)

Comment: What's the id used for?

Comment: Do not use rand, it is neither secure nor unique. From the docs: "rand is not cryptographically secure. You should not rely on it in security-sensitive situations."

Comment: @zaph, It seems to me the OP is already aware of that since they are looking for an alternative!

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, yor are right: `sometimes we want something more reliable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what it's used for.

If it's used to identify as your variable name suggests, it needs to be unique.

For example, if two people shared the same session id, they would share the same session.

For example, if two people shared the same temporary file name, they would share the same file.

It's an encryption key, you want it to be random so it has the most entropy possible.

Comment: I have updated my question. So for my purpose I may use any of these two modules, may not?

Comment: Obviously not, since one creates a unique id, and the other one doesn't.